# opencart add shipping rates for each individual product in multiple stores

Tags: opencart

Hi I have created multiple stores I want to add multiple shipping rates in each products for each store.

eg: I have added a product "Laptop" so I can add multiple shipping rates

US(store) Shipping rate of Laptop = $10

AED(store) Shipping price of Laptop = $5

Above same thing for other products like I have added a "Watch" so the watch is too small then a laptop

US(store) Shipping rate of Watch=$1
AED(store) Shipping rate of Watch=$1

any suggestion or idea code or extension?

Comment: Check this: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=23044

Comment: This is per item shipping rates for each store but I need shipping rates for each product please check question I have updated it.

Comment: Did you check all screenshots of that  extension? Especially the 3rd screenshot.

Comment: Yea I have checked all of screenshots, and you are talking about this http://image.opencart.com/extension/561e055f6f74d-resize-500x500.jpg
I need different and multiple shipping rates for all products, eg: after adding laptop I add product "Watch" so the "Watch" have too different shipment price